# How do I print repeating images in a US-letter sized document in landscape orientation?

Tags: gimp

I just started using GIMP 2.8
I've watched many tutorials and read the user manual but I'm still not sure how I can make this work. I would like to create a US-letter sized document in landscape orientation (11" wide and 8.5" tall), and insert into that document two images, and align those images symmetrically around a vertical axis at the middle of the document. Could someone point me in the right direction for how to go about achieving this?

Edit: I'm very much new to image manipulation software so if anyone can recommend a better and easier way to get the effect I've described, please share!

2nd Edit: Changed all mentions of "portrait" to "landscape"

Comment: Why don't you use a word processor in which you include the two pictures? (btw, "Portrait" is taller than wide, what you describe is 'Lands cape').

Comment: woops, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it. As for why I'm not using word processors, the only one I can use is Google Docs and it's hard to align them just right using Docs because I have to manually resize each image in order to make them fit in one page. And by manually resizing them and without the aid of alignment tools, I can't get the symmetrical look I'm trying to get.

Comment: maybe OpenOffice or similar? The only dynamic alternative I can think of is html table with a bit of CSS